# Why I can't enable openstack "floating ip port forwarding" funcation on horizon

Tags: openstack, dashboard, floating, horizon

My openstack version is ussuri.

I configured the function of "Floating IP port forwarding" according to this document: https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/ussuri/admin/config-fip-port-forwardings.html

But I can't see "Configure Floating IP Port Forwarding Rules" on Dashboard under "Floating IPs"

Are there any other configurations of Neutron or horizon that need to be modified?

Someone has turned on the function of "Floating IP Port Forwarding"： https://openstackdocs.safeswisscloud.ch/en/howto/ht-port-forward.html

But I don't know how to do that, hoping for help.

Thanks.

Comment: It often takes time until new features get Horizon support, and there are plenty of features that are not implemented yet and might never be.

Comment: I see someone has turned on the function of "Floating IP Port Forwarding"
https://openstackdocs.safeswisscloud.ch/en/howto/ht-port-forward.html
But I don't know how to do that

Comment: I've same issue here (cannot see the horizon mapping feature) despise I believe I have latest release installed (wallaby)

Comment: after checking current Horizon code at https://opendev.org/openstack/horizon/src/branch/master/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/ it seem to me that the feature in question is a custom extension of the safeswisscloud.ch